# Php switch Case Why wont my Default page trigger when wrong url is enter

Tags: php, html

Hi I'm working on a page switch code, the default page does not seem to load for some reason can anyone help? at the moment I can enter a random URL but it just shows page not found.

the default show be triggering to the PHPMyAdmin page error
which is the `views/404.php` folder.
but it doesnt. I can seem to understand why it doesnt.

```
<?php
//begin the webpage
//index page selector placed into an array for options for the user to select


//session started recording attributes
session_start();

error_reporting(0);

//including other view class and model class function to be used on this page
include 'views/viewClass.php';
include 'classes/modelClass.php';


class PageSelector {
    public function run() {
        //has the user decided which page to go to?
        //if not then we will direct him to the homepage
        if(!$_GET['page']) {
            $_GET['page'] = 'Home';
        }

        //extending a new model class
        $model = new Model;

        //get the page information
        $pageInfo = $model -> getPageInfo($_GET['page']);

        //select which page to include when the user clicks
        //on either register/home/my account/my bids/my sell/completed auctions/edit etc..etc..etc..
        switch($_GET['page']) {

            case 'Register':
                include 'views/register.php';
                $view = new HomeView($pageInfo, $model);
                break;

            case 'Home':
                include 'views/homeView.php';
                $view = new HomeView($pageInfo, $model);
                break;

            case 'My Account':
                include 'views/myaccount.php';
                $view = new myaccount($pageInfo, $model);
                break;

            case 'My Bids':
                include 'views/mybids.php';
                $view = new Mybids($pageInfo, $model);
                break;

            case 'My Sell':
                include 'views/mysell.php';
                $view = new mysell($pageInfo, $model);
                break;

            case 'Completed Auctions':
                include 'views/checkout.php';
                $view = new checkout($pageInfo, $model);
                break;

            case 'editProduct':
                include 'views/editProductView.php';
                $view = new EditProductView($pageInfo, $model);
                break;

            case 'addProduct':
                include 'views/addProductView.php';
                $view = new AddProductView($pageInfo, $model);
                break;

            case 'deleteProduct':
                include 'views/deleteProductView.php';
                $view = new DeleteProductView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

            case 'deleteUser':
                include 'views/deleteUserView.php';
                $view = new DeleteUserView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

            case 'search':
                include 'views/search.php';
                $view = new search($pageInfo, $model);
            break;   

            case 'product':
                include 'views/productView.php';
                $view = new ProductView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

            default: 
                include 'views/404.php';
                $view = new error($pageInfo,$model);




        }
        echo $view -> displayPage();

    }    

}

$pageSelect = new PageSelector();
$pageSelect -> run();
//calls the selector to run after user has selected.
```

Comment: does it work for all the other pages?

Comment: are you entering a random URL or a random value for page?

Comment: Are rewrite rules in place?

Comment: all other pages work, defualt one doesnt seem to work , even when i enter a wrong url doesnt trigger to the 404 page

Comment: entering random value for page

Comment: http://localhost/school/Tradingpost1v/Tradingpost%20Serverside/www/index.php?page=out

Comment: check if each of the values for default echo out anything

Comment: comes to a page, and it says it does not exists

Comment: What does your 404.php page include? "Comes to a page, does not exist" sounds right ;)

Comment: Does view/404.php exist? I notice you have all error reporting turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
if(!$_GET['page']) {
```

To

```
if(!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] == '') {
```

Comment: where do i place that? >< im pretty new to php

Comment: Just change the line in your code "if(!$_GET['page']) {" to the one I mentioned.

Comment: ooo i tried it but it didnt work still same problem just says page does not exist when entering a false page

Comment: <?php

class error extends View {
        
    protected function displayContent() {
       
        $html .= '<div id="pageinfo">';
            $html .= '<h2>'.$this -> pageInfo['pageHeading'].'</h2>';
           
            $html .= '</div>';
                 
    
            $html .= '<div id="Space">';
            
            $html .= 'OOOPS an ERROR have occured we will redirect you';
            
            header("refresh:5;index.php?page=Home");



            $html .= '</div>';
           

 

?>

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are properly routing the 404s to this file. What is happening is that because the 404 doesn't have a $_GET['page'] your code is setting itself to be home and loading the home page.

Assuming this is the index.php file I would add a conditional to check for this and change the default to a case 404. This is the new code in full.

```
<?php
//begin the webpage
//index page selector placed into an array for options for the user to select


//session started recording attributes
session_start();

error_reporting(0);

//including other view class and model class function to be used on this page
include 'views/viewClass.php';
include 'classes/modelClass.php';


class PageSelector {
    public function run() {
    //Check to make sure they are loading a legit page first
    if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != 'index.php'){
        $_GET['page'] = '404';
    }
    //has the user decided which page to go to?
    //if not then we will direct him to the homepage
    if(!$_GET['page']) {
        $_GET['page'] = 'Home';
    }

    //extending a new model class
    $model = new Model;

    //get the page information
    $pageInfo = $model -> getPageInfo($_GET['page']);

    //select which page to include when the user clicks
    //on either register/home/my account/my bids/my sell/completed auctions/edit etc..etc..etc..
    switch($_GET['page']) {

        case 'Register':
            include 'views/register.php';
            $view = new HomeView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'Home':
            include 'views/homeView.php';
            $view = new HomeView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'My Account':
            include 'views/myaccount.php';
            $view = new myaccount($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'My Bids':
            include 'views/mybids.php';
            $view = new Mybids($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'My Sell':
            include 'views/mysell.php';
            $view = new mysell($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'Completed Auctions':
            include 'views/checkout.php';
            $view = new checkout($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'editProduct':
            include 'views/editProductView.php';
            $view = new EditProductView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'addProduct':
            include 'views/addProductView.php';
            $view = new AddProductView($pageInfo, $model);
            break;

        case 'deleteProduct':
            include 'views/deleteProductView.php';
            $view = new DeleteProductView($pageInfo, $model);
        break;

        case 'deleteUser':
            include 'views/deleteUserView.php';
            $view = new DeleteUserView($pageInfo, $model);
        break;

        case 'search':
            include 'views/search.php';
            $view = new search($pageInfo, $model);
        break;   

        case 'product':
            include 'views/productView.php';
            $view = new ProductView($pageInfo, $model);
        break;

        case '404': 
            include 'views/404.php';
            $view = new error($pageInfo,$model);
        break;



        }
        echo $view -> displayPage();

    }    

}

$pageSelect = new PageSelector();
$pageSelect -> run();
//calls the selector to run after user has selected.
```

Comment: i just tried the whole code cut and pasted on mine it didnt work :(

Comment: Try echoing the $_GET['page'] right before the switch. Personally I would do a 404 when you determine this is a 404 page and then have that go to a case for the 404. After that I would have a default that goes to a different error page which is more like a 500 error for an error.